# Revert Skype contact list to be like it was before the latest update

Tags: skype

My Skype client has been updated to the latest version (on Windows 7). In the new version it's grouped all my Facebook contacts in along with my normal Skype contacts. I've tried to get used to it but it's being an absolute pain when you start a conversation with a contact,  only to find your speaking to them through their Facebook account and not their Skype.

Is there any way I can revert my Skype client to split the Skype contacts from the Facebook contacts like it was before this update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the "All" contacts list. In this list, you will see your skype and facebook contacts grouped together.

You can switch to the "Skype" contacts list in order to see only your skype contacts. You can do this via the menus: Contacts -> Contact Lists -> Skype :

[image: Skype contacts list]

You can also sign out of Facebook and only be online on Skype. You can do this via the menus: Skype -> Online status -> Facebook -> Offline :

[image: Offline on Facebook]

You can also disconnect your Skype account from your facebook account via the gear menu in the Skype Home screen:

[image: Disconnect from Facebook]

---

EDIT: It looks like the Facebook tab is gone from the new version of Skype. But you can switch trough your lists quickly using the thing that looks like a combobox that is below the search bar. It takes an extra click, but it does the same job.

[image: Switch lists]

Comment: This helps, but I was hoping to regain the tabs that were on the old Skype so I could switch between the two more easily. But thank you for this :)

Comment: Oh, i see. You can use the combobox-looking thing that is below the search bar to have that functionality. It takes an extra click (versus the old tabs), but at least you don't have to go trough the menus. I have edited my answer to include a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Skype (Newest Skype Update 8.12.0.14) And BOOM. No contacts. All the recent calls are there but, zero Contacts. I uninstalled the "New" Skype and reinstalled the last "Stable" version 7.40.0.104 and voila! My Contacts are back. Query, is this a "Bug" or is the Contacts list hidden somewhere?